# C - "Connection refused" on an already open socket

Tags: c, sockets, connection

I'm working on an application that opens a data stream TCP socket to another.
After the connection is open and accepted by the server, I send a "login" message which is received by the server successfully, the server attempts to send a "success" message. This is where things get weird.

The write on the server fails and errno is set to "Broken pipe".
The client polls on the file descriptor waiting for data to read which fails as well. On it errno is set to "Connection refused".

All connections are TCP on the loopback device.
Using tcpdump, I can see that FIN is send from the client to the server.
It can be found [here](http://www.fileserve.com/file/rkAhDat/dump.pcap).

How can errno be "Connection refused" if the connection was already established?
What might cause this behavior? The client code is synchronous without any threads and no one else has access to the file descriptor.

If it matters, the server is the Asterisk manager.

Snippets of the client code (real code has error checking, separated functions and such):

```
struct sockaddr_in sa;
int fd;

fd = sock_socket(SOCK_STREAM, 0, 0);.
MZERO(sa);
sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
sa.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
sa.sin_port = htons(MANAGER_PORT);

connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof(sa));
sprintf(buf,
    "Action: Login\r\n"
    "Username: %s\r\n"
    "Secret: %s\r\n"
    "Events: %s\r\n"
    "ActionID: %d\r\n"
    "\r\n",
    MANAGER_USERNAME, MANAGER_PASSWORD, events, manager_action_id++)

write(fd, buf, strlen(buf));

{
    struct pollfd fds = {fd, POLLIN, 0};

    if (poll(&fds, 1, timeout) <= 0)
        return -1; /* This is where the client fails with "Connection refused" */
}
```

Thanks!

P.S. - Sorry for responding to comments inside the question itself, but I created the question before I created an account and I'm not allowed to add comments.

Comment: You need to show us your client source code.

Comment: Are you sure nobody calls `close` or `shutdown` ? Can you show us the capture file ?

Comment: `poll` should never return -1 with errno `ECONNREFUSED`.  It may have returned 0 in which case errno is not set; it is just left over from some previous system call.  Try running the client under `strace` to make sure you have the sequence of calls and errors correct.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to "Broken Pipe",i guess you are trying to write some stuff in a closed socket so a SIG_PIPE signal is released,in this case.Declare `<signal.h>` and install signal operations in a manner of,like `signal(SIG_PIPE,SIG_IGN)`